# Request quote form in popup on php page

Tags: jquery, popup

I have a popup Getquote form. Which pops up on clicking 'Get quote' button shown under each product on the php webpage. The Get quote button is within php 'while' loop of 'mysql_fetch_array' function to show products from database.

```
<!--Fetching product from database & Getquote button-->

<?php
$sno = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{
echo $row [3]; 
  $product_name =$row [3]; 
?>
    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
      <input type="button" value="Get Quote" id="button-quote"  /></a>
<?php
$sno++;
}
 ?>
```

On clicking 'Get Quote' button, the product name is also shown on the popup form, but the problem is its showing the last listed product for all other products.

```
<!--CSS of popup box-->
    <style>
    .black_overlay{
        display: none;
        position:fixed;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        opacity:.80;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
    .white_content {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 10px solid #0288BE;
        background-color: white;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    a:link {text-decoration:none;}
</style>

 <!--Request Quote in Popup code-->

 <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
   <div id="light" class="white_content">
<div id="response"></div>
<table align="right">
<tr>
<td align="right"> <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>  

 </td></tr></table> 
          <form action="phpform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()" name="quoteForm">
<h2>Request A Quote </h2>
<br/>

<table cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td>Product Name</td>
<td><b><?php echo $product_name; ?></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Get A Quote" /></td>
</tr> </table> 
</form>        
</div>
```

To understand the problem see working example [Click here](http://myweblo.com/imc/index.php?mod=products&category=Flame%20Spray%20Gun)

Its showing product 'Gun IMC-5K' in popup even on clicking on Getquote button on other products.
How to get different product name in the Getquote form for each product.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is like this you are looping over result.
and storing $row[3] in $product_name. The loop will execute as many times as number of rows in your database. that all time it will be override with new value in loop. But when loop is complete last value will be stay in $product_name. :)

for this you need to use jQuery:

First replace your a tag like:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick ="popupinfo('<?php echo $row[3]; ?>')">
      <input type="button" value="Get Quote" id="button-quote"  /></a>
```

Comment line:

//    $product_name = $row[3];

write java script like

```
function popupinfo(product_name)
{
     document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
     document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
     document.getElementById('productname').value = product_name;
}
```

Just give id to your td

```
<td id="productname"><b><?php echo $product_name; ?></b></td>
```

I had not tested it so some syntax error may there(typing mistake). But this is the way you can use. There are Other options also there.
But Hope this help you.

Comment: I've done as you said, but its showing "Undefined variable: product_name" in the popup.
If u like, I can show u on my screen through Teamviewer

Comment: I got it. Just remove  <b><?php echo $product_name; ?></b> just keep it <td id="productname"></td>

Comment: On removing  <b><?php echo $product_name; ?></b>, its not showing product name in the popup.. I need it in <input type="hidden" name="product_name"   value="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" /> also to post its value to the database.

Comment: Replace this line document.getElementById('productname').value = product_name; with document.getElementById('productname').innerHTML = "<b>"+product_name+"<b>";